# How can I detect onKeyUp in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

How can I detect onKeyUp in AngularJS?

I'm looking for an 'ngOnkeyup' directive, similar to ngChange, but I can't find anything suitable.

If there isn't such a directive, is there a clean way to call into the controller from a browser-native onkeyup event?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

**EDIT: see second answer below from maklemenz which refers to the new built-in ng-keyup directive**

You could use the [angular-ui library](http://angular-ui.github.com/):

With angular-ui, you can just do

```
<input ui-event="{keyup: 'myFn($event)'}"
```

If you don't want to use another library, the most efficient and simple way to do this is:

JS

```
myApp.directive('onKeyup', function() {
  return function(scope, elm, attrs) {
    elm.bind("keyup", function() {
      scope.$apply(attrs.onKeyup);
    });
  };
});
```

HTML:

```
<input on-keyup="count = count + 1">
```

---

**Edit**: If you wanted to detect which key was pressed, you have two basic options really.  You could add an attribute to the directive to handle the allowed keys within the directive, or you could pass the key pressed to your controller. I would generally recommend the directive handles the key method.

Here's an example of both ways: http://jsfiddle.net/bYUa3/2

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  How do I get which key was pressed with your non-angular-ui solution?

Comment: I added something to the main post about detecting the key.

Comment: Those are just what I need.  Thanks for your help, I'm really starting to love using AngularJS.  It feels bad to be throwing away a year's experience of using KnockoutJS, but AngularJS just looks to be so much more maintainable and approachable for new devs.

Comment: Here's another take. (I forked your jsfiddle Andy.) Using $parse and calling it with a scope mixin allows more flexibility -- the expression can be a function or an inlined expression and do whatever with the `$key` value. http://jsfiddle.net/g6Yvb/2/

Comment: This answer is not kind of out of date, as the `ng-keyup` directive was added. (Disclaimer: I am not experienced with AngularJS at all). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18534733/2916086 instead

Answer (score 78):

For everyone looking for that feature today,
please use the official [ng-keyup](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngKeyup) directive:

```
<input type="text" ng-keyup="{expression}" />
```

Comment: Is there a way to get a key up or keydown event on the window object in general; so I can check if Ctrl is being pressed?

Comment: @TheRedPea You could put your ng-app and your ng-keyup on <html />. Then add the function to the $rootScope or also add ng-controller. Not tested but should work.

Answer (score 7):

You'll have to create your custom directive if default directives are not enough.
Something like this, may be?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
  <body ng-controller="ctrl">
    <input ng-onkeyup="keyup()"/>
    <script src="js/lib/angular-1.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      angular.module('app', []).directive('ngOnkeyup', function() {
        return {
          restrict: 'A',
          scope: {
            func: '&ngOnkeyup'
          },
          link: function( scope, elem, attrs ) {
            elem.bind('keyup', scope.func);
          }
        };
      });

      function ctrl($scope) {
        $scope.keyup = function() {
          alert('keyup fired');
        };
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the already mentioned Event Binder, you can now use these convenient ui-key* directives from Angular UI:

```
<textarea
 ui-keypress="{13:'keypressCallback($event)'}">
</textarea>
<textarea
  ui-keydown="{'enter alt-space':'keypressCallback($event)'}">
</textarea>
<textarea
  ui-keyup="{'enter':'keypressCallback($event)'}">
</textarea>

<script>
$scope.keypressCallback = function($event) {
alert('Voila!');
$event.preventDefault();
};
</script>
```

http://angular-ui.github.io/#/directives-keypress

Answer (score 5):

Just to help anyone out there who, like me, wanted to fire the event only on a certain key.  Here is the code using `ng-keyup` that calls my `cancel()` function when, and only when, escape is pressed.  To find out what keycode you want look at [this website](http://keycode.info/)

```
ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 27 ? cancel() : ''"
```

Note that as @maklemenz mentioned this uses the in built Angular directive available now

Answer (score 0):

FYI - I was just searching for this today and it appears that there is a branch in Angular's github that addresses the issue of keyup keydown.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/1622

It has been merged into master... HOWEVER it does not look like it will appear in a release until 1.1.3

In order to build the angular with the ng-keyup option in place you can download the code from git and run `rake package` on the folder. Of course on windows that means installing Node.js and Ruby and possibly some other hoops (I was having fork errors on win32)

Though, I did get the "built in" keyup in the end.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question corectly, you are looking for the ng-keyup directive. Here is a link: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngKeyup

Answer (score 0):

I know my answer is too late but I hope it can be helpful to some folks.
If you are looking for a fast and easy method you can use this:

```js
 // in the controller
    
    // get element by id, you can use by class...
    var element = angular.element('#element');
    
    element.keyup(function () {
    console.log('keyup fired');
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<input id="element" type="text" />
```