# How can I watch for an ng-submit event or enter keypress on sub forms in angular.js?

Tags: angularjs, keypress, angularjs-ng-form

I have a multi-step form with 5 steps. I'd like the user to be able to use the enter key to submit each of the sub forms to trigger validation and moving to the next sub form on success. I can't find a way to do this. I was thinking perhaps I could add `ng-keydown` events to each of the sub forms (or a custom directive binding to `onkeydown`) and watch for the enter key `keyCode`.

**Does anybody have experience with getting this to work in Angular? How would you add this functionality?**

Here's a brief HTML sample of the sub-forms. Assume the "Next Step" button is triggering `$scope.nextStep()` within an angular controller and that subsequently performs validation to determine if the user can move to the next step or if a validation error is displayed.

```
<form>
    <div ng-form="step1"></div>
    <div ng-form="step2"></div>
    <div ng-form="step3"></div>
    <div ng-form="step4"></div>
    <div ng-form="step5"></div>

    <button type="button" class="btn" ng-click="nextStep()">Next Step</button>
</form>
```

---

**For those of you reading and looking for more info on the answer**

I track the form step inside of my controller's `$scope.current_step`. Using that, I'm able to use `$scope[$scope.current_step]` to reference the current form. With @Vova's accepted answer below, I would do something similar to the following:

```
$scope.myFunc = function(event) {
    if (!$scope.isFormValid()) {
        return false;
    } 

    // trigger next step (which handles it's own validation)
    $scope.nextStep();
};

$scope.isFormValid = function() {
    // check if the current form is invalid
    if ($scope[$scope.current_step].$pristine
        || $scope[$scope.current_step].$invalid
    ) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
};
```

Comment: create a simple demo in plunker

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using [ng-keyup](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngKeyup) directive set function that can get the Enter (13) key event, and fire up your validation/stepForward function.

other solution, add angular-ui, and do something like this:

```
<form ui-keypress="{13:'myFunc($event)'}">
  ... input fields ...
</form>
```

more solutions:
[Submit form on pressing Enter with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417125/submit-form-on-pressing-enter-with-angularjs)

Comment: Thanks for the ui-keypress reference. I think this will provide an elegant solution to what I'm looking for. Essentially, `myFunc()` will then check the validity of `$scope.current_form` before triggering `$scope.nextStep()`, if valid, in my case. I'm not interested in overall form submission; just the submission of the currently active sub form.