# Get value of input field from Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using the directive from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17364716/1377021) to run a function when the enter key is pressed in an input field.

How can I pass the value of the input field `element.val()` to the function the directive calls? Or pass the input field `element` to the function, to clear the value after it's retrieved.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" ng-enter="newField()" />
```

**JS**

```
app.directive('ngEnter', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown keypress", function(event) {
            if(event.which === 13) {
                element.val(); // value of input field

                scope.$apply(function(){
                    scope.$eval(attrs.ngEnter); // passed to this function
                });

                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    };
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just do this:

```
var func = scope.$eval(attrs.ngEnter);
func();
```

and have the controller take care of the value logic. See the code below. **[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/iNosaJe/6/edit)**

Also, I don't recommend prefixing your custom directives with `ng`. I suggest coming up with your own prefix as a namespace. `ng` is for Angular's core. In my examples, I am using `my-enter` rather than `ng-enter`.

**Sample markup:**

```
  <input 
    type="text" 
    ng-model="foo" 
    my-enter="myFunc"
    placeholder="Type stuff!"
  >
  <p ng-repeat="val in cachedVals track by $index">{{val}}</p>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.cachedVals = [];
  $scope.foo = '';
  $scope.myFunc = function() {
    $scope.cachedVals.push($scope.foo);
    $scope.foo = '';
  };
});

app.directive('myEnter', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    element.bind("keydown keypress", function(event) {
      if(event.which === 13) {
        scope.$apply(function(){
          var func = scope.$eval(attrs.myEnter);
          func();
        });
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    });
  };
});
```

Here's an example with an isolated scope - you don't need to `$eval`.

```
app.directive('myEnter', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      func: '=myEnter'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.bind("keydown keypress", function(event) {
        if(event.which === 13) {  
          scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.func();
          });  
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Hmm.. not quite. I'm just trying to get the value when the user hits enter, use it, then clear the input field. ng-change executes on each keypress.

Comment: @nathancahill yeah, I'm working on the directive and see that now. That was just my first thought. I should be done soon!

Comment: @nathancahill I still need to make an improvement, but my original recommendation works.

Comment: Is $eval or scope.$apply better?

Comment: @nathancahill hmm? They are unrelated. The directive at the bottom of my post is the one I suggest. `$apply` is needed because you're firing angular code outside of angular (the event block). `$eval` gets a scope value from a string of its name.

Comment: @nathancahill I updated one last time. Check it out - important note about `ng`.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `ng-submit`? I have created a fiddle to show you how do to what you are after without requiring your own directive.

http://jsfiddle.net/a6k7g/

Obviously this answer depends on your requirements, and the form complexity.

Comment: ng-submit works on form elements, this is just an input field.

Comment: So wrap it in a form element!