# How to click save button using Angular JS Custom Directive onEnter

Tags: angularjs, directive

I want to click Save button when I press Enter..For this, I created a directive named "onEnter" but I don't know how to trigger 'ng-click' on savebutton wheen Enter key press. I made a sample here

http://plnkr.co/edit/vnphuxQRQQfVmWtsGhip?p=preview

Please suggest!

Answer (score 0):

If you change:

```
<input type="button".. value="Save" />
```

to

```
<input type="submit".. value="Save"/>
```

Then the form will act normally listening for the enter event. No need for a directive as it is already built in.

Angular also supports an `ng-submit` event. This post will provide more information:

[Submit form on pressing Enter with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417125/submit-form-on-pressing-enter-with-angularjs)