# Stop angular.js route changing on press enter in input box

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form with multiple input boxes and when the first input box has focus and if I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> then route is changing and navigating somewhere.
How can I stop it?

Comment: Most probably when you press enter the form submits... that's why it's navigating to another page.  Please post your form code. Are using ng-submit ?

Comment: Use something like preventDefault or return false in you ng-submit handler.

Comment: I am not using ng-submit and there is no button type="submit".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form is submitted hitting enter.
You can try adding an event that listen to the Enter keypressed like this:

```
<input ... ng-keypress="keyPressed($event)">
```

Then in your controller you can just prevent the default behavior for Enter key.

```
$scope.keyPressed = function(event) {
  if (event.which === 13){
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

You can find more info in several other questions around SO

[Submit form on pressing Enter with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417125/submit-form-on-pressing-enter-with-angularjs?lq=1)
[How to use a keypress event in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17470790/how-to-use-a-keypress-event-in-angularjs)

Comment: Thanks for answer but I don't wanna break the by default functionality.