# Close Twitter typeahead on Enter key in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, twitter-typeahead

I have a **search field** using [Twitter typeahead](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/) with this [Angular directive](https://github.com/Siyfion/angular-typeahead).

I can't figure out how to **close** the *typeahead suggestions* when I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> (i.e. when none of the suggestions are picked). Can anyone help me out please?

I can fire search through a [separate directive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17364716/1678614) when <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed, but I don't know how to close the suggestions.

I could use this hack when I run search:

```
jQuery('.tt-dropdown-menu').hide();
jQuery('.tt-hint').hide();
```

and `jQuery('.tt-hint').show();` on other key presses, but there must be a more proper way.

Answer (score 2):

You could put the typeahead inside a form and adding a `display: none` submit button

```
 <form novalidate>
      <input type="text"             
             ng-model="myModel"
             typeahead="something.value for something in myList" />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="display: none">
</form>
```

That would close the typeahead directive when you hit enter