# set focus on span on tab using angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have below structure for my span tag,

```
    <a href="#"> </a>
    <span  class="spanclass" ng-click="clickfunction()">

    </span>
```

1. It is said that we need to add **tabindex=-1** to the span
2. and then **set** **focus** to the **span element**.

Initially I thought like on ng-blur of anchor tag, I can call a function where I can set the focus as below

```
    $('.spanclass').attr("tabIndex", -1).focus();
```

Then Im able to get focus on it however, when I press enter ng-click is not getting called, which is happening if I do by clicking directly.Also here I mixed both angular js and jquery which might not be correct.

May I know how we can implement above two steps  using angular js and on what event.

Thanks,
Balaji

Comment: you don't need `tabIndex` to set -1

Comment: you can use UI-keypress for ref check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417125/submit-form-on-pressing-enter-with-angularjs

Comment: @rjdmello thanks for the link, but my issue is like I cant use blur event on anchor tag for setting tab-index for the span,  may I know on what event I can set the tabindex for the span to -1, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in other answers, changing to a button would make the most sense.

If you MUST use a span element, then you can add a directive to perform a function on Enter keypress, like found here: [How to use a keypress event in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17470790/how-to-use-a-keypress-event-in-angularjs)

**Javascript:**

```
app.directive('ngEnter', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
            if(event.which === 13) {
                scope.$apply(function (){
                    scope.$eval(attrs.ngEnter);
                });

                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    };
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-enter="doSomething()">    
</div>
```

Comment: Also, mixing JQuery and AngularJS is perfectly fine, as long as you include JQuery first. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: Thanks mofojed I will try this and let you know

Answer (score 1):

It will be more semantic to change the span to a button (you can still style it as you wish)

```
    ...
    <style>
        .span {
            border: none;
            background: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="ctrlr">
        <a href="#" tabindex="2">First</a>
        <button class="span" ng-click="clickfunction()" tabindex="1">
            Second
        </button>
    </div>

    <script>
        angular.module('app', []);
        angular.module('app').controller('ctrlr', function ($scope) {
            $scope.clickfunction = function () {
                alert('a')
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

```js
        angular.module('app', []);
        angular.module('app').controller('ctrlr', function ($scope) {
            $scope.clickfunction = function () {
                alert('a')
            }
        });
```

```css
        .span {
            border: none;
            background: none;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="ctrlr">
        <a href="#" tabindex="2">First</a>
        <button class="span" ng-click="clickfunction()" tabindex="1">
            Second
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi,  thanks for your answer, Im not supposed to change from span to button , is there any other alternative

Comment: @potatopeelings is correct, `span`s should only be used with inline elements, not something that you normally interact with. Can you change the `span` into an `a` tag?

Comment: That's sad, but yeah it's possible - you need to handle the keydown event for the span. See http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201302/making_elements_keyboard_focusable_and_clickable/ > Button 3. the right way to do it would be to make a directive.

Comment: @jimmyboh in my case it is an online element only

Comment: @potatopeelings OK I will try with keydown event thank you

Answer (score 1):

Although the above answer by @mofojed has been accepted.
But here are some more clarification that will make this post complete.

You can set focus on a focusable HTML element which includes anchor tags, HTML inputs, selects, text areas, buttons, any embedded elements as well as any element with a tabindex

Note that tabindex should not be -1 if you want to focus on the span by adding a tabindex. Make the tabindex a positive number.