# angular.js keypress directive event mysteriously not firing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, angularjs-directive, angularjs-digest

I followed this example [Submit form on pressing Enter with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417125/submit-form-on-pressing-enter-with-angularjs)

but I cannot get it to work. It is totally baffling. Why does the keypress event not get trapped by my directive?

http://plnkr.co/edit/A9oio2F61yHssE49aiCb?p=preview

```
app.directive('enterKey', function($log) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown keypress", function(event) {
            if(event.which === 13) {

                scope.$apply(function(){
                    scope.$eval(attrs.ngEnter, {'event': event});
                });
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is copy paste mistake in your directive `attrs.ngEnter` should be `attrs.enterKey` as you changed the directive name.

```
scope.$apply(function(){
    scope.$eval(attrs.enterKey, {'event': event});
});
```

Additionally you need to add `event` parameter inside your `alertMe` method to accept event

```
$scope.alertMe = function(event) {
    alert('I am alerted!');
}
```

Comment: I'm such an idiot. Thank you.

Comment: @metalaureate not a problem.. Glad to help you.. Thanks :)