# Submit form on pressing Enter with AngularJS using angular material

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

[Submit form on pressing Enter with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417125/submit-form-on-pressing-enter-with-angularjs)
This question uses html5 buttons but I'm using Angular Material Button as

```
<div class="card-action no-border text-right">
  <md-button class="color-primary sign-btn" ng-disabled="logForm.$invalid" ng-click="login()"> Sign In</md-button>
</div>
```

But how to work with it

Answer (score 3):

You can create an Enter directive as below:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('directives')
    .directive('eopdEnter', function () {
        return function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
                if (event.which === 13) {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        scope.$eval(attrs.eopdEnter, {'event': event});
                    });

                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        };
    });
```

And use it in this way:

```
<div class="card-action no-border text-right">
  <md-button class="color-primary sign-btn" eopd-enter="login()" ng-disabled="logForm.$invalid" ng-click="login()"> Sign In</md-button>
</div>
```

Comment: It is really helpful. Thanks. It saved my day as well!!