# how to format a input field as user type in content

Tags: validation, input, angularjs, formatter, directive

http://jsfiddle.net/x3azn/ZRVyF/

for this sample, how can I change the formatting to be done on the input, so that input displays

```
<input val='0.00'>
```

and I type 1

```
<input val='0.01'>
```

and I type 9 and 9

```
<input val='1.99'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't think of an easier way to achieve this but to create your own directive, so you can listen the keyboard event on the input element and format the output accordingly. This SO question might be helpful: [How can I detect onKeyUp in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264188/how-can-i-detect-onkeyup-in-angularjs)

Comment: Now I have seen this thing called $formatter inside the built in angular form input, is there perhaps a way I can use that or was that still deprecated?