# AngularJS : Model update detection and change event

Tags: angularjs

I wonder what is the best way to handle the change event of input with Angular. In fact we can listen model updates but the corresponding listeners are triggered at each character entered not only when the input updates ended.

Thanks for your help.
Thierry

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264188/how-can-i-detect-onkeyup-in-angularjs

Comment: You can create a directive to trigger your handler when say the focus on the input is lost (onblur)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use that example to be inspired of it. It's a Directive with `ENTER` :

```
app.directive('ngEnter', function() {
        return function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind("keydown keypress", function(event) {
                if(event.which === 13) {
                    scope.$apply(function(){
                        scope.$eval(attrs.onEnter);
                    });

                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        };
    });
```

HTML :

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-enter="doSomething()">    
</div>
```