# Why to increment a dummy variable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am going through various angular examples, and sometimes I see angular developers increases a dummy variable like this below. Later they don't refer this variable in the controller scope. How should I interpret/read this?

```
<input on-keyup="count = count + 1">
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's `on-keyup`? don't you mean `onkeyup`? In which case, this counts the keypresses.

Comment: I found this here in answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11267263/743027 (there is posted jsfiddle). I saw this in some other example too, which don't remember now.

Comment: Well I've never seen it that way. Who knows, it might even work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the answer you reference, `on-keyup` is a user-defined directive, which is used as follows:

```
<input on-keyup="count = count + 1">
```

`count = count + 1` is an expression that the directive executes using $eval when a `keyup` event is detected:

```
scope.$apply(attrs.onKeyup);
```

This will increment a `count` property on the $scope object.  If the property does not exist, it is created.  If this variable/property is not referenced by the controller, or the view, or logged, then it really is a dummy variable.

In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zhYAz/), I added `{{count}}` to the view.

Comment: I see now. So there is no special underlying need to makes this adding in HTML. I made some checks and I could go with <input on-keyup=""> and make this calculation inside a controller http://jsfiddle.net/JNGGC/ .

Comment: @flyer, just FYI, you can simplify your fiddle a bit further: `<input on-keyup>` and `scope.$apply();`.

Comment: In other hand if I extend your fiddle to http://jsfiddle.net/zhYAz/2/ it makes things more complex when we look at the console (`prev` and `next` are different then applied to bound view). I would expect the `prev` is always less than `next`.

Comment: @flyer, you are changing `scope.next` after calling $apply, so the view will not be updated with the change.  You'll need to call $apply again: http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/zhYAz/3/

Comment: Ohh. my $scope.next was updated every next call. That's make sens. Thank you.